# Loading a class and checking for method presence without resolving the class

Tags: java, dependencies, runtime, classloader

I am trying to load a class from a folder to check for the implementation of a specific method. The class has some imports that are not present in the folder or its subfolders. Loading the class with `Class clazz = Class.forName(className, false, classLoader);` works fine, but when I call `clazz.getDeclaredMethod("methodName")` then I get a `NoClassDefFoundError` because some imports cannot be resolved.

Is there a possibility to *examine* a class at runtime (I do not intend to call methods or instantiate it) without loading dependencies?

If not, how else can I check a class for a specific method implementation when I have a classes-folder as a starting point?

Comment: Could I ask what you're building that has such a requirement?

Comment: @Keith I need to add a wrapper around a class the static analysis of a Java webservice. For that purpose I need to find the classes implementing the methods being called when a request comes in (`doGet()` and `doPost()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question.

I don't think you want to roll your own byte code parser, so try [Apache BCEL](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/) or [Spring ASM](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/asm/package-summary.html). Both allow you to read/write class files without having to load them.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do that with a library such as [Apache Commons BCEL](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/).

> The Byte Code Engineering Library (Apache Commons BCEL™) is intended to give users a convenient way to **analyze**, create, and manipulate (binary) Java **class files** (those ending with .class).

Answer (score 0):

you could try executing `javap ' from your program and parsing the output. For example:

```
javap Driver
Compiled from "Driver.java"
public class Driver {
    public Driver();
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
```